# How to insert <script> with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, insert, script-tag

I'm using Prototype insert function to appent some html which contains `<script>...</script>`. And within this script I'm defining a new function. And as I read [here](http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails-spinoffs/2005-October/001045.html) Prototype runs script that is inside `<script>` tags and then removes it, but all functions should remain accessible. But from that moment I can't run my new function.

```
 $('some_id').insert({ bottom: '<script> ... </script>' });
```

How to solve it? The best would be that it won't remove `<script>` tags.

EDIT:

By now I did it like this:

```
var add_here = document.getElementById('prepayment_group_items');
var src = document.createElement('div');
src.innerHTML = 'a lot of html with script tags';
add_here.appendChild(src);
```

Comment: You might want to include the script you are trying to execute in your example.

Also, you might try adding:

    type="text/javascript"

to your script element.

Comment: Script contains something like: function update_38172() {...}. Where this number is generated by Rails. This function works when I add to this script: update_38172(); it run, but only once. After inserting is finished `<script>` part is completly removed from html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will add a script tag to the head of the page, with whatever content you pass it.

```
function insertScript(script_text) {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.type = "text/javascript";

    var script = document.createTextNode(script_text);
    script_tag.appendChild(script);

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_tag);
}
```

I'm more familiar with jQuery than Prototype, so I just did this in pure JS.

Translate the part where I create the element and the part where I get the HEAD element into Prototype if you want, but use the call to **appendChild** instead of Prototype's *insert* function, since it will just do what you ask, rather than eval-ing the JS.

Of course, now that I look at what you're asking for, you might also just try changing the code you're inserting to something like:

```
window.update_12345 = function() {...}
```

I'm not sure if that will fit it or not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I already did it using appendChild, but I was putting a little more then just `<script>`. I appended my solution to question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include JavaScript into the head, you might do something like this:

```
$$('head').first().insert({
    bottom: new Element('script', {
        type: 'text/javascript'
    }).update('function helloWorldToConsole(){console.log("Hello World!")}')
});
```

This creates a new SCRIPT tag and inserts it to the bottom of your HEAD. But it would be much nicer if you add an external JavaScript file like this:

```
$$('head').first().insert({
    bottom: new Element('script', {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: 'http://www.example.com/path/file.js'
    })
});
```

You can than use the functions later in your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
    $('<script></script>',{
     type:'custom',
     id:'script1'
    }).appendTo('head').attr('type','text/javascript');

    $('#script1').append(< add js code here >);
```

});